# Can't push github project to azure with git

Tags: git, azure

I've signed up to the new azure trial. I have a project on github that I want to push to my new azure web site, so following the instructions on the azure site, I add the azure site as a new `remote`:

```
git remote add azure https://me@app.scm.azurewebsites.net/app.git
git push azure master
```

When I push, I'm asked for my password, and then get:

```
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify faile
d while accessing https://me@app.scm.azurewebsites.net/app.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

It's a vanilla git setup, so I've not set anything funky up. The only thing I've done is download and use github windows to work with the repo.

**Update:**

This seems to be something that is only affecting the `North Europe` data centers..

Comment: Can you ping me in https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/kudu

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're looking into this issue at the moment. I'll update this answer when everything is resolved.

**EDIT**

We had an issue with the certificate on some of our front ends and we restored them.

Comment: Thanks dfowler. I didn't get chance to say how impressed with the level of support you gave me to troubleshoot the issue. I'll be around on jabbr if you need anything else from me

Comment: It's working now - can you update the answer with the details and I'll accept

Answer (score 3):

You mention avoiding  the issue with `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true`, but that isn't the right solution.

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK
```

That means the ssl transaction has trouble finding and tructing the root CA (Certificate Authority) used by [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/)

All the trusted CAs are reference in Git by the setting `http.sslcainfo`. Make sure you have:

```
git config –system http.sslcainfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

If that doesn't work, you can try and mention the full path:

```
git config --global http.sslcainfo "/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

or:

```
git config --global http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\Bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

---

If nothing works, then, as [dfowler (Developer on the ASP.NET Team )](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45091/dfowler)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11712796/6309) suggests, there might be an issue with the CA chain being broken somehow (ie, incomplete on Azure's side):

[image: CA chain illustration]

Comment: Note: for a hosted service on Azure, see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg981937.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help! dfowler jumped in when he saw the issue, and has been helping me look into this via jabbr. But I appreciate the detailed response

Comment: @MattRoberts yes, the answer is more for others with the same message ;)